# PuTTY Shortcuts to Minimize, Maximize, Restore, and Move the Window

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, putty

The Alt+Space command doesn't work on Putty (at least for me). So, if I've to minimize or maximize my PuTTY windows, I'll have to use the mouse which is very uncomfortable. Did anyone get around this problem?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Never mind, there's a setting for that.

Window -> Behavior -> (System Menu Appears on Alt+SPACE checkbox)

Answer (score 28):

On windows, there are specific keyboard shortcuts that help in window behavior. A few that I know are :

1. window key + up = Maximize
2. window key + down = Restore Down/Undo Maximize + Minimize (for bringing back the window after minimizing, use Alt + tab)
3. window key + right = Split to right half
4. window key + left = Split to left half

Comment: Unfortunately, these don't work if you're in full-screen (Alt-Enter) mode, but they do work in a normal window.

Answer (score 7):

You should go to Window/Behavior and check Full screen on Alt-Enter. Save the session, so you'll be able to use this shortcut to convert into full screen mode.